# Why is the MongoDB constant in index.js not required when using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As an aspiring developer, I was watching a video about mongoose on YouTube and noticed that the developer removed the MongoDB constant variable requiring MongoDB and just created one for Mongoose.

They say its an object modeling tool so if it's a tool for MongoDB shouldn't the MongoDB variable still be required in the file with the variables and routers?

I will admit I don't have good backend knowledge as a beginner so if you can explain in layman's terms that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since mongoose being an ODM (Object Document Mapper) specifically for mongodb, you only need a connection to a particular database of mongo to be defined via mongoose...And the rest of the work would be done by mongoose. ( the only thing that still needs beside the mongoose connection is your mongo instance running in the background or whatever you're using specifically !) If you want to know in detail, read this article by Jamie Munro -> https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-and-nodejs--cms-29527 .. Hope this helps :)

Mongoose connection to mongodb

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

// mentioning url for specific mongo database along with the port
let DB_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name';

// creating a connection for mongoose to act to specific db
var connection =  mongoose.createConnection(DB_URL,{ useNewUrlParser: true });

// if error occurs, then create connection or else connect directly
try {
  mongoose.connect(DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (err) {
  mongoose.createConnection(constants.DB_URL);
}

// consoling the success message if connection is opened or else displaying error if error is present
mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => console.log('MongoDB Running'))
  .on('error', e => {
    throw e;
  });
```

Comment: so we can delete const mongodb = require('mongodb'); since mongoose is used to connect to the database. I'm guess it is only used to create the database and the express framework hosts it so the mongodb library is no longer needed?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have mongoose present, you don't need to "require" mongodb library. All you need is to mention the url for mongoose to create a connection and then connect (or reject) to mongodb. I have updated my answer to add the connection details just in case to understand clearly. Hope this helps !